# Sandbox a java applet

Tags: virtual-machine

I heard that minecraft server is very leaky, can consume a lot of resources very quickly.  People say to use a virtual machine, all well and good.  I'm making an application to automate server setup, and I'd like my whole application (including minecraft) to run in an ultra basic auto setup vm (or something similar).  I've heard of mineos, but I'm not sure if that can be set up very quickly.  The vm will be so basic it won't even have a ui.  I'm using a Mac, not planning to distribute the server WITH the application but have it download from the minecraft server, not modified.

I want it to be like a one-click-done solution for the end user, they don't have to worry about minecraft server gobbling up resources because it's be in a controllable virtual machine.

Distrubuting minecraft server (Notch's property) could be an issue, but if anyone knows about that if be happy to hear.

Comment: Not sure I follow - all java applications (including applets) run inside a sandbox - the JVM. You shouldn't have to worry about it getting "outside" that sandbox. Do you have a concrete example of this happening that is repeatable?

Comment: I do have research but am not able to supply it at the moment.

Comment: This sites video seems to imply that minecraft is leaky.  It also redistributes minecraft server with the OS, which is against Notch's TOS but anyway: http://minecraft.codeemo.com/adv_features.html

Comment: Well, being a programming website, without some code, or more research data, it's going to be very difficult to answer your question. Your question, as is, is too open ended.

That being said, with all the server and VM elements to this, you might be better served asking your question on SuperUser.com

Comment: My statement isn't concrete; just the basis of others saying that using a virtual machine would contain minecraft server's resources.  I'd like this question moved to superuser, moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend for a server to be fully configured and only for your user to only have to download and 'open' it, what you're seeking is known as an 'appliance'.  [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf) supports the open-standard of such appliances, allowing a single file to be distributed and it contains all the virtualized hardware info as well as the OS/filesystem.  A number of other formats exist, such as [Turnkey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/).

In all likelihood, I would find [MineOS CRUX](http://mineos.codeemo.com/) to be perfectly suited for this sort of one-click-done, since the OS was designed for pretty much exactly what you're trying to do...only without the configure-the-hardware-for-the-user (it uses an ISO and an installer, the process you would automate for the end-user).

That said, this distribution has never at any point packaged Minecraft files, as clearly stated: "this Linux distro does not contain ANY Minecraft files. The scripts are, however, designed to download/update files directly from the source: http://minecraft.net"

Hope this answers all the concerns, despite being an old thread.

Comment: Thanks!  I was just searching this today, and I thought it would be a good choice too.  Is MineOS CRUX the same as MineOS?

Comment: MineOS has a few variants, all of which are very different from eachother.  [MineOS (microcore)](http://minecraft.codeemo.com/) is the first variant, for which development has been since been halted.  [MineOS CRUX](http://minecraft.codeemo.com/buildmineos/) is the actively developed one based on an entirely different distro (CRUX) which is dramatically more sophisticated and polished.  If you have any questions, too, there's a large community at [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mineos)